# Google Play Service Attribute "theme" has already been defined

Tags: android

I am using google play service to get location service and I got the following error:

```
Error:Attribute "theme" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar -M /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package sponseer.com.sponseer -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/markthien/android/sponseer/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values/values.xml:119: error: Attribute "theme" has already been defined
```

My build.gradle is like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:2.0.7'
}
```

I have been searching around SO here and google but still can't solve it. it was saying that the attribute "theme" is conflicting between play service and appcompat. I try to change to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

but still the same.

My gradle version is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
```

Appreciate any help please. Thanks !

regards,
Mark Thien